# How can I open a magnet link in a console app?

Tags: c#, console-application, magnet-uri

WebClient's openread don't seem to do the job, in what other way can I open magnet links? uTorrent is the default handler so I need the links "executed".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `Process.Start`. I know this works for HTTP URLs (launching them in your default Web browser), so if your system has `magnet` URLs associated with uTorrent, then this should launch the URL in uTorrent.

```
Process.Start("magnet:?xt=urn:sha1:YNCKHTQCWBTRNJIV4WNAE52SJUQCZO5C");
```

Comment: hey, do you know how do I add magnet URLs association with the OS?

Comment: @Kubi, probably the same way you add any other URL association. There's nothing particularly special about magnet URLs.